# Сортировка большой HTML таблицы: сервер или клиент?

Tags: html, сервер, сортировка, клиент

Добрый день!

Возникла следующая задача: необходимо реализовать сортировку таблицы HTML с большим объемом строк (несколько десятков тысяч) по клику на заголовки столбцов. Хочется узнать, есть ли смысл делать ее чисто на клиенте (посредством js плагинов, наподобие tablesorter), или при таком объеме данных сортировка быстрее будет работать через обращение к серверу (ajax)?

Comment: ну так вы жу не все 10 тыщ строк выводите в таблицу за раз, зачем ajax вообще postbeck и без заморочек

Comment: @Naumov при сортировке таблицы должны сортироваться не только те данные которые выведены, но и те, которые возможно сейчас находятся на "другой странице" (не выведены)

Comment: Лучше в sql делайте сортировку и отдавайте клиенту только ту страницу на которой он находится. Все в одном запросе решается.